# What constructor is called in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have an object

```
class A {
    public:
    int bar();
};

A foo() {return A();}
int A::bar() {return 5;}
```

And then I do this:

```
int i = foo().bar();
```

What constructor is invoked for the temporary value created when `foo()` returns?

Comment: The question can just be reduced to `A foo() { return A(); }`, none of the rest is relevant. And then... which constructor do you think? It's easy to simply instrument and find out. Do you question the results you got?

Comment: @Barry not necessarily easy to find by testing, because of copy elision

Comment: As I've found out - my problem was caused by copy elision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is:

```
A foo() {return A();}
```

When `foo()` is called , the sequence of effects is:

1. Temporary created by `A()` using `A`'s default constructor.
2. *Return value object* of type `A` created using copy/move constructor, with step 1's temporary as argument (that is, move constructor if it exists, otherwise copy constructor).
3. Temporary from step 1 is destructed.

However this is a [copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) context, so the compiler might combine all 3 steps into one, and create the *return value object* using `A`'s default constructor.

What happens to the *return value object* depends on what the calling code does. There might be further copy elision. In the usage:

```
int i = foo().bar();
```

nothing else happens; `bar()` is called on the *return value object*, the value is assigned to `i`, and then the return value object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling with C++11, inside `foo` when `return A()` ran it calls default constructor. Then when it returns from foo `move constructor` is called. But if you're compiling with older versions first default constructor is called then copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor is called. Maybe trying this makes it clearer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  A() {
    cout << "A's default ctor" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  return 0;
}
```